# jekyll different line break rules for post and Staticman comments

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I would like to apply different line break rules for posts written in Markdown and comments received from Staticman.

Here is an example in **markdown**:

```
Test
New line without a gap

New line with a gap.
```

Here is how it is delivered by **Staticman json**:

```
message: "Test\r\nNew line without a gap\r\n\r\nNew line with a gap."
```

**In post**, I would like it to be rendered as:

```
<p>Test
New line without a gap</p>

<p>New line with a gap.</p>
```

**In comments**, it should include `<br>` after `Test`:

```
<p>Test<br>
New line without a gap</p>

<p>New line with a gap.</p>
```

I can achieve either of these formatting with kramdown setting `hard_wrap` in `_config.yml` but I don't know how to set different settings for posts and comments.

Maybe I can add some filter to the comments.html which now looks as the following:

```
{{ include.message | strip_html | markdownify html=content }}
```

I tried `newline_to_br`. It is not an option. It introduces too many breaks:

```
<p>Test<br>
New line without a gap</p><br>
<br>
<p>New line with a gap.</p><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I fixed it with the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS:

```
.comment p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```